24.04. run gui app as different user
How do I start a gui-app as a different user from a background script?
To be more specific: I am using a notebook in different environments, some of it require a proxy for network connection. To setup all clients (apt, snap, gsettings, nextcloud-desktop) automatically I am using a trigger script in /etc/NetworkManager/dispatcher.d/. For starting apps in user-context I've found a script on stackexchange:
DISPLAY_ID=":$(find /tmp/.X11-unix/* \! -user gdm | sed 's#/tmp/.X11-unix/X##' | head -n 1)"
USER=$(who | grep tty | awk '{print $1}')
USER_ID=$(id -u "$USER")
function user-session() {
    _environment=("DISPLAY=$DISPLAY_ID" "DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS=unix:path=/run/user/$USER_ID/bus")
    sudo -Hu "$USER" env "${_environment[@]}" "$@"
}
# use it for instance like this:
user-session gsettings set org.gnome.system.proxy mode none

This does no longer work for gui apps like the nextcloud client (because of wayland?).
This nextcloud client uses a static config file for the network config, so I have to kill the client, rewrite the config and finally restart the client. The latter has to be done in the context of the currently logged in user, but the trigger script runs as root.
So how do I start the nextcloud client for the current gui user from a script running as root triggered by a background job on a current (24.04) ubuntu?
I am using this procedure since several years. Maybe there exists some simpler solution?
Mathias
